# Arps in virtual machines and virtual interfaces

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, virtualbox, wireshark

I am using wireshark inside and outside of a virtual machine, inside oracle box virtual box.

Outside of oracle box my main OS basically shows up two arps, the reuter asking who am I and my machine telling the reuter I am there. This seems normal.

However I am not very sure of how this works inside the virtual machine.

I see the following first A) PcsCompu Arp Who has 10.0.2.2? Tell 10.0.2.15
And second B) RealtekU Arp 10.0.2.2 is at 52:54:00:12:35:02

Realtek seems the default driver of my wifi antenna. The PcsCompu... no idea.
 10.0.2.2 is connecting to openvpn but from there on I have no idea of what is doing PcsCompu nor where is sending or what is doing PcsCompu.

To further confuse me I am seing inside the virtual machine the following interfaces: 10.0.2.15 10.0.2.2, 10.8.8.1 and 10.8.89.12 ( this last two which so far wireshark does not show up connecting to anything)

Any idea for me to understand what is happening here would be appreciated.
I know this is a very general question, but any idea of what is happening in my machine is really the question I gonna ask first. 
Second, is it possible for virtual network interfaces to be malignant (example, someone enters into your computer, setups a virtual network interface which will broadcast the data somewhere else?)

Comment: Very briefly: ARP works the same way, but the MAC addresses are invented (virtual hardware). The upper 3 bytes of the MAC address identify the vendor, so you get random vendors for VM interfaces. So look at the MAC address of the interfaces. The VM host will also have interfaces.

Comment: The VM has no antenna (because its plugged to the host which has an antenna) and would use a virtual ethernet I guess. So maybe in my case PcsCompu is the way its called the ethernet virtual interface? Also in any case, macs inside the VM are different and have different macs than outside of the VM. In my case I think I can identify one of the interfaces because my antenna is realtek although it has a different denomination outside of the virtual machine.

Comment: Can you first disable _Resolve network addresses_ (and perhaps even _Resolve physical addresses_) in Wireshark's _View → Name Resolution_ menu? You don't need the program to be showing misleading info right now.

Comment: @grawity Hmm well I suppouse you are right. All resolves disabled from now on (none matches as expected anything I know)